# Java socket is closed - When posting SOAP request

Tags: java, soap

first time posting a question on this site. I've been working on a project where I have to generate a signed(Header x509) SOAP request and submit it to an https URL where the webservice resides. Thus far I've been able to generate the Signed SOAP request, but I'm getting a socket is closed exception when I post the request. Can anyone help me figure out what is my code missing that could be causing this error. Thank you in advance!

Below is my code for how I'm posting the request, and the error:

```
            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(new File("my keystore"), "mypassword".toCharArray(),
                            new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .build();

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    sslcontext,
                    new String[] { "TLSv1" },
                    null,
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setSocketTimeout(300 * 1000)
                    .setConnectTimeout(300 * 1000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(300 * 1000)
                    .build();
            HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom() //CloseableHttpClient 
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                    .build();

            HttpPost httpPost;
            httpPost = new HttpPost("https://my webservice");

            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "test/xml");

            File input = new File(esbXmlFile);

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(input);
            InputStreamEntity inputStreamEntity = new InputStreamEntity(inputStream);
            httpPost.setEntity(inputStreamEntity);


            String content = null;
            int statusCode = 1; //statusCode is response code form WS.
            try
             {
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                 statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                 System.out.println("statusCode : " + statusCode);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

             }
            catch (SocketException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                 e.getStackTrace();
             }

 I get this error: 
            DEBUG (main) [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] - Starting handshake
        2016-11-28 16:24:04,019 DEBUG (main) [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] - http-outgoing-1: Shutdown connection
        2016-11-28 16:24:04,019 DEBUG (main) [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] - Socket is closed
        java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
                at java.net.Socket.setSoLinger(Socket.java:986)
                at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.shutdown(BHttpConnectionBase.java:305)
                at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.shutdown(DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.java:97)
                at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.shutdown(LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java:89)
                at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolEntry.shutdownConnection(CPoolEntry.java:74)
                at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.shutdown(CPoolProxy.java:96)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ConnectionHolder.abortConnection(ConnectionHolder.java:127)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:352)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
                at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to set:
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "test/xml");
into
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");
difference is test/xml into text/xml